# golang tcp socket does not send message after write immediately

Tags: sockets, tcp, go

My GO version is 1.1.1

the sever recieved messages after connection close, but NoDelay was setted.

Is there something wrong

```
addr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:5432")
conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, addr)
defer conn.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("connect fail")
    return
}
err = conn.SetNoDelay(true)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

for {
    var message string
    _, err := fmt.Scanln(&message)
    if err != nil && err.Error() != "unexpected newline" {
        fmt.Println("input finished", err)
        break
    }

    if message == "" {
        fmt.Println("no input, end")
        break
    }
    // message = fmt.Sprintf("%s\n",message) 
    //fmt.Fprintf(conn, message) // send immediately but following message won't send any more
    conn.Write([]byte(message)) // won't send until connection close
}
```

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't need to do `conn.SetNoDelay(true)` as it's true by default. (http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn.SetNoDelay). Also, `Write` returns the number of bytes written, and an error. Try doing `_, err = conn.Write([]byte(message))` and see if that sheds some light on the problem.

Comment: I just tested your code (with a couple of changes, nothing major, see http://play.golang.org/p/CaVynZMXWJ) and it seems to work as expected. Are you sure the problem isn't on the server end?

Comment: yes I just add conn.SetNoDelay(true) to ensure that

Comment: @Intermernet oh you are right , it's my fault, I will explain it in my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything vitally wrong with your code so I'm guessing the error is on the server end.

If you create a local TCP server on port 5432 you can test this.

Try running the below server code and then test your client code against it. It just echos all received data to stdout.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:5432")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        go func(c net.Conn) {
            defer c.Close()
            io.Copy(os.Stdout, c)
        }(conn)
    }
}
```

You should see each line sent to the client printed (without the newline) as soon as you hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is on the server end.

```
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
// I didn't put it in for loop
message, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
}
```

Comment: Easy mistake to make :-)