# TCPConn Write does nothing until socket closes or newline is written

Tags: go, tcp

Calling TCPConn.Write without any newline or null byte delimiter doesn't seem to do anything until the socket or writer is closed.

In this example I'd expect conn.Write to trigger the read on the server as soon as the write is complete, but nothing happens until the socket is closed. If I Write a string with a newline character before writing the ones without it works fine. Is this intended behavior? Are delimiters required? Or am I just missing something here..

Server

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    addr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", ":8080")
    l, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp4", addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    defer l.Close()

    for {
        var conn *net.TCPConn
        if conn, err = l.AcceptTCP(); err != nil {
            log.Println(err.Error())
            continue
        }

        log.Println("client connected")
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn *net.TCPConn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        var b = make([]byte, 128)
        bytesRead, err := conn.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }

        log.Printf("got: %s\n", string(b[:bytesRead]))
    }

    log.Println("client disconnected")
}
```

Client

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    addr, _ := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    // uncommenting the following line will make the following writes work as expected
    //conn.Write([]byte("hello world\n"))

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        conn.Write([]byte("hello"))
        log.Println("wrote hello")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915952/golang-tcp-socket-does-not-send-message-after-write-immediately

Comment: The network doesn't care whether you send a `\n` or not. Is this the *exact* code you're running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for giving it a go, I ran it on a Ubuntu vm where it worked as expected. So, as of 1.5.1 for Windows, it seems to be a bug.

**Edit:**

Turns out it's Eset Smart Security's protocol filtering, go isn't the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Running the code verbatim (client write hello world remains commented) shows:

Server:

```
2015/12/04 09:57:00 client connected
2015/12/04 09:57:00 got: hello
2015/12/04 09:57:01 got: hello
2015/12/04 09:57:02 got: hello
2015/12/04 09:57:03 got: hello
2015/12/04 09:57:04 got: hello
2015/12/04 09:57:06 client disconnected
```

Client:

```
2015/12/04 09:57:00 wrote hello
2015/12/04 09:57:01 wrote hello
2015/12/04 09:57:02 wrote hello
2015/12/04 09:57:03 wrote hello
2015/12/04 09:57:04 wrote hello
```

It seems to work as expected, the server outputs once per second, as the client writes.

This was tested on:
go version devel +54bd5a7 Sat Nov 21 10:19:16 2015 +0000 linux/amd64

What go version are you running?

Comment: Tested here too. version go1.4.2 linux/amd64 and works fine

Comment: Just tried 1.5.1 linux/amd64, works as expected. I guess it's a bug?